# How WPF mouse double click event works?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mouseclick-event

I have mouse double click event on wpf data grid in code behind as follow:

```
async void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     var dg = (DataGrid)o;
     var item = (MyCustomType)dg.SelectedItem;
     await MyAsyncMethod(item.Id);
}
```

and on line

```
var dg = (DataGrid)o;
```

NullReferenceException occured. Morover, I have no way to show value during debugging session.
When I change my method to:

```
async void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(o is DataGrid && (o as DataGrid).SelectedItem !=null)
    {
         await MyAsyncMethod(((MyCustomType)(o as DataGrid).SelectedItem).Id);
    }
}
```

everythings seems to work correctly. How async mouse double click works that I can not invoke event like first representation?

Comment: Are you sure that it's a `NullReferenceException` in the first case? If `o` is really `null` the second version should not work either.

Comment: Anyway, the second listing would not throw an exception when `o` is `null`.

Comment: Yes, nullreferenceexception and i cannot put breakpoint on first brace in first method version

Comment: are you sure that `dg.SelectedItem;` is really `MyCustomType`?

Comment: Yes, I am sure tht. In debugger session error occured after var dg = (DataGrid)o; line

Comment: add screen of your debug window to the Q.

Comment: and show your xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the first and second code snippet is that the first doesn't check whether there actually is a `SelectedItem` available.

Use the `as` operator like this and you should be fine:

```
async void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = (DataGrid)o;
    var item = dg.SelectedItem as MyCustomType;
    if (item != null)
        await MyAsyncMethod(item.Id);
}
```

Your issue has nothing to do with the event itself nor `async`/`await`.

**Edit:**

If `MyCustomType` is a `struct` you cannot use the `as` operator but you should still check whether the `SelectedItem` property is actually set:

```
async void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object o, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = (DataGrid)o;
    if (dg.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        await MyAsyncMethod(((MyCustomType)dg.SelectedItem)item.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asyn/await part of the answer. Unfortunately if MyCustomType is struct than 'as' operator does not work.

Comment: That's true. But you should still check whether the SelectedItem != null like you do in your second snippet.